# Outlier detection in small sets

Tags: c++, algorithm, outliers

Is there a good algorithm for detecting outliers in small sets of decimal numbers? The best idea I have come up with so far is a kind of recursive standard deviation based approach, but it seems a bit computationally expensive.

I'm using c++, so any existing functionality in say Boost or other maths helper libraries is welcome in your answers.

Thanks.

Comment: it seems you got the wrong stack* site... are you looking for math...? http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @elcuco I think its on topic for SO, since the op mentioned computational efficiency.

Comment: just how "small" are these sets? 1/5/10 - which one's the outlier?

Comment: @ValekHalfHeart while I think that this is a great question... I do think that he will get better answers in a dedicated site with math people.

Comment: According to WIKI "There is no rigid mathematical definition of what constitutes an outlier; determining whether or not an observation is an outlier is ultimately a subjective exercise." So you probably need to define criteria and then ask for implementation.

Comment: @elcuco http://stats.stackexchange.com/ would be a good site also.

Comment: You can do it in O(n) time with an online variance algorithm (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance#Online_algorithm) and then a second pass to mark outliers.

Comment: @MadScienceDreams make it an answer!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in O(n) time with an online variance algorithm (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance#Online_algorithm) and then a second pass to mark outliers.